# HTML: Flash not loading in IE (while working perfectly under Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a JSP web page that loads the `Uploadify` flash using javascript/jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'queueSizeLimit' : 99999,
        'uploadLimit' : 99999,
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Poker hand history Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.txt; *.xml',
        'onUploadComplete' : function(file) { countFiles = countFiles + 1; },
        'onQueueComplete' : function(queueData) { refreshText(); },
        'removeTimeout' : 1,                
        'width'    : 276,
        'swf'      : '<%=rootUrl%>/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<%=rootUrl%>/FileReceiver?<%=FileReceiver.TRANSACTION_ID_PARAM%>=<%=transactionId%>'
    });
});
```

This works perfectly under Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work with Internet Explorer (I'm using IE11): any idea/hint on what I should be looking at? (IE11 console doesn't indicate any error, just a couple of minor warnings)

The page can be found at this location (see the "Select files" button under Chrome/Firefox that doesn't work with IE11):

```
http://72.249.82.50/
```

Thanks!
Thomas

Comment: did you check if Flash is working at all in IE11?

Comment: Yes, flash is working perfectly. Somehow I have the feeling that it is related to URLs (to css file and to swf file), as it stopped working when I mapped my website to the root of the URL...